# Why data not received in PHP when i POST it from android?

Tags: php, android, post, get

i am trying to send name=zaeem to my PHP server side but when i send it from android i didn't get anything in php side . My  PHP code is on free hosting . below is my Android and PHP code .

**this code is for GET request**

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {


            String responseData = "";
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            Integer result = 0;
            try {
                /* forming th java.net.URL object */
                URL url = new URL("http://za*******pk/testregister.php/");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                /* optional request header */
              //  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                /* optional request header */
               // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                /* for Get request */
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes("name=zaeem");

                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("code", statusCode + "");
                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
                if (statusCode == 200) {

                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    responseData = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                    result = 1; // Successful

                } else {
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return responseData;

        }
```

**This code is for POST request**

private class MyTaskPost extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String responseData = "";
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        Integer result = 0;
        try {
            /* forming th java.net.URL object */
            URL url = new URL("http://za****e.pk/testregister.php");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            /* optional request header */
            //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            /* optional request header */
            //  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            /* for Get request */
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("name=zaeem");
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("code", statusCode+"");
            /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
            if (statusCode ==  200) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"200",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                responseData = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                result = 1; // Successful

            }else{
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return responseData;

    }
```

And my PHP side code is  (This is hosted on free hosting)

```
$name1=$_GET['name'];
$name1=$_POST['name'];
$name1=$_REQUEST['name'];


 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database   
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_users(name, email, gcm_regid,created_at) VALUES('$name1', 'email', 'longtext', NOW())");

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE id = 1") or die(mysql_error());

             if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
             {

                 echo 'more than 1 user';
             }
```

when i use POST method i get 200 code but still data not added to database.

Comment: Is your code in php working fine ?

Comment: @SyedTayyabAbbas


$name1=$_GET['name'];
$name1=$_POST['name'];
$name1=$_REQUEST['name'];


 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database 
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_users(name, email, gcm_regid, created_at) VALUES('$name1', 'email', 'longtext', NOW())");
        
    
 
          
         echo 'showed';

Comment: is the database being modified by this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey zaeem sattar "Try this Code Its work and  if you still get an error then check your php file with dummy data"

```
    StringBuilder data;

    URL urls;

    HttpURLConnection connection;

    OutputStreamWriter writeQueryString = null;

    BufferedReader readData = null;

    InputStream is = null;

    try {

        urls = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection
                .setFixedLengthStreamingMode(queryString.getBytes().length);

        writeQueryString = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");

        writeQueryString.write(queryString);

        writeQueryString.flush();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {    

            is = connection.getInputStream();

            data = new StringBuilder();
            if (is != null) {
                readData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "ISO-8859-1"));

                while ((lineRead = readData.readLine()) != null) {
                    data.append(lineRead);
                }

                output = data.toString();
            }
        } else {
            output = "Problem With Connection";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("errors","HttpClient:"+e.toString());
    }
```

@zaeemsattar  following reasons for your error's                                      1. free hosting have some proxy problem. when you send Request from android php then page not found(404) kind of error occurs. base on my past experience with this free hostings...                                                       2.your php code function now()  and the $name1 those three variable with 3 different get post and request method having error ..so solution   for that you can use date function with single single cot's and  based on android request if use post on android side then use that on php side to  that solve your problem                 3. try dummy data first on php page like  default $name1="zaeem"; with this  run php page     good luck

Comment: @priyash 

$name1=$_GET['name'];
$name1=$_POST['name'];
$name1=$_REQUEST['name'];


 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database 
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_users(name, email, gcm_regid, created_at) VALUES('$name1', 'email', 'longtext', NOW())");
        
    
 
          
         echo 'showed';

Comment: php side code is simple . if it have any mistake kindly correct it

Comment: @zaeemsattar free hosting have some proxy problem. when you send Request from android php then page not found(404) kind of error occurs. base on my past experience with this free hostings...

Comment: but when i hit my URL from browser it adds value to database .. if it has proxy then i should allow me to hit me url from browser. what do you think ?

Comment: when you request from android app scenario change it work in browser but when debug app that time 404 page not found or other server error display

Comment: Actually the problem is that i got 200 response code but still value not added to database

Comment: just log "output" variable on android side in above code if you get ok response  that will give you php side response.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost = new HttpPost("http://za****e.pk/testregister.php");
try {

   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","abcxyz"));
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

}catch(Exception e){ }
```

You can get the values in php script

```
$name1=$_POST['name'];
```

Comment: httpClient is deprecated @kami .